# Multiplication of elementary matrices

Tags: matrices

There is inversial matrix

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    19 & 7 \\
    -38 & 14  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
that can be written as a multiplication of K elementary matrices in the form: $$A=B1B2....Bk$$

need to write matrix in form $$2x2K$$ $$B1$$ is 2 first columns from left and $$B2$$ next 2 columns etc

like this:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    B1 & B1 & B2 & B2 \\
    B1 & B1 & B2 & B2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
etc

I did this:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    19 & 7 \\
    -38 & 14  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    19 & 7 \\
    0 & 28  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    19 & 7 \\
    0 & 1  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    19 & 0 \\
    0 & 1  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Could you try to fix the formatting more and explain more thoroughly what you mean by "need to write matrix in form $2x2K$?

Comment: Just ignore this part... I need to find B1 B2 B3... Bk

Comment: @HelpMePlease Do you know the Gauss-Jordan algorithm? Apply it to your matrix to reduce it to the identity, and keep track of all the steps you take along the way.
Those steps are your $B_k^{-1}, \dots, B_1^{-1}$. Just invert them all and you're done!

https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/matrix-algebra/gauss-jordan-elimination

Comment: I kinda messed it up... can you write me please the answer so I will know what I did wrong.

Comment: I just followed the rules and it worked but I have no clue what I did and I feel like a machine